# Как правильно это реализиовать

Tags: c#, массивы

Как правильно выполнить это задание?
Задан массив из k чисел. Найти числа, входящие в массив только один раз.

```
      private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int k;
        k = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int[] nums = new int[k];
        int[] arrSort = new int[k];
        Random rand = new Random();
        textBox.Text += "Creat Massiv: ";

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            nums[i] = rand.Next(50);
            textBox.Text += " " + Convert.ToString(nums[i]);
        }

        textBox.Text += "\n";

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < nums.Length; j++)
            {
                if (nums[i] != nums[j])
                {
                    arrSort[j] = nums[i];
                }
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < arrSort.Length; j++)
        {

            textBox.Text += " " + Convert.ToString(arrSort[j]);
        }
    }
```

Вместо цифр, выводит 0.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, что за код вы пытались написать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
  nums[i] = rand.Next(50);
  textBox.Text += " " + Convert.ToString(nums[i]);
}
textBox.Text += "\n";

List<int> result = nums.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
string resultText = string.Join(",", result);
textBox.Text += resultText;
```

Comment: Как это реализовать?

Comment: Нет, подумай, что я некий Том Сойер, который решил скинуть своё задание на других, просто не понимаю сильно С#

Comment: @JZ_52 после цикла с  `nums[i] = rand.Next(50);`

Comment: Так, добавил, но System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] 1 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] 17 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] 44 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

Comment: @JZ_52 это что?

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < nums.Length; j++)
            {
                nums[j] = rand.Next(50);
                textBox.Text += " " + Convert.ToString(nums[j]);
                List<int> result = nums.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
                string resultText = string.Join(",", result);
            }
Ничего не происходит, просто выводит массив новый. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Если выводить result, то будет ошибка System.Collections.Generic.List1

Comment: @JZ_52 Кто же говорит, что надо выводить `result`? Взгляните на текущий вариант ответа.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92056/discussion-between-jz-52-and-igor).